# how to I uncheck boxes when checking others with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have this html -

```
<ol class="subproduct">
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="Multidispositivo" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test<span class="price"><span>+2</span>€</span></h3>
    <p>test words</p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="Multidispositivo" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test</h3>
    <p>test words</p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="15 min extra" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test/h3>
    <p>test words</p>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="extra2" value="Multidispositivo" />
    <p class="checkbox"></p>
    <h3>test</h3>
    <p>test words</p>
</li>
</ol>
```

which I need to add a class to the li on 'checking' the checkbox. Currently I use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subproduct input:checkbox').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
     }
  });
});
```

but I need it so that only ever one checkbox is checked by the user so if they check another box it removes the class of any other

How is this possible?

Comment: Do you want uncheck checkboxes or remove class from `li` elements?

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, I want to remove the class from the li element when clicking on a new li checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this: **[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TRsra/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.subproduct input:checkbox').change(function(){
   $('.subproduct input:checkbox').not(this).attr("checked",false);
   $(".subproduct li").removeClass("checked");
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked");
   }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/4g74n/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subproduct input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
       $('ol li').removeClass('checked');
       $(this).prop('checked',true);
       $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    } else {
       $(this).parent().removeClass('checked');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the class of all `<li>`'s on chnage event... using `removeClass()`;...and then if checked `toggleClass()` of that `<li>`

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subproduct input:checkbox').change(function(){
   $(".subproduct li").removeClass("checked"); //<---here
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this).parent().toggleClass("checked"); // and using addClass("checked") here is better .. 
    }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this 
   http://jsfiddle.net/QHuV9/4/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subproduct input:checkbox').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         $(this).parent("li").addClass("checked");
     }

      else {
      $(this).parent("li").removeClass("checked");
      }
  });
});
```

I hope i am taking your question rite

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subproduct input:checkbox').change(function(){
     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
         $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('checked');
         $(this).parent().addClass("checked");
     }
  });
});
```

And I would advise to use `<input type="radio">` so that the behavior will be understood by user.